# How to avoid 'Choose Account' screen with Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, restful-authentication

Our app is importing the next 1000 events from a user's Google calendar API.  We ran into the problem where nginx would timeout.  To get around this I'm putting the pagination data into a session variable and making separate HTTP requests to the API.  This works except for one problem: every time we make a new HTTP request the API asks the user to choose which account they want to use (one user with multiple gmail accounts).  I would have thought that the pagination data would include account selection but this is apparently not the case.  How can I programmatically select the email account within the HTTP request?

Comment: You can try to use [EMAIL Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#java), if it is possible to help you with your problem.

To use it, send an HTTP request to a specific URL that represents a particular user's setting. The request will be one of three types—either a POST request that performs a create operation, for creating new labels, filters, or send-as aliases—or a PUT request that performs an update operation, for changing any of the updatable settings listed above—or a GET request that retrieves all the settings for labels, forwarding, and many others.

Answer (score -1):

You can store it once

```
public static void setmCredential(GoogleAccountCredential _mCredential) {
        mCredential = _mCredential;
        mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                .setApplicationName("YourApplicationName")
                .build();
}
```

And then when caliing pass it like this

```
new MakeRequestTask(AccountCredential.mService).execute();
```